# RadioButtons and an EventTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a dependency property and i want it populated with the headers of some radio buttons when the IsChecked event is true. I've searched a way to accomplish this but all i've seen until now are animation examples. I understand i need a binding inside that EventTrigger definition but how would it look like?

```
            <RadioButton Content="Header1" 
                         Margin="4" 
                         Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

On it's IsChecked property is true, i want a way to populate my previously defined dependency property with it's header ( Header 1 in this case )

```
    public string HeaderSelected
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderSelectedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderSelectedProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HeaderSelected.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderSelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderSelected", typeof(string), typeof(HeaderTestClass), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
```

I think i will try something like this:

```
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="IsChecked">
                           <ei:ChangePropertyAction 
                           TargetObject="{Binding}"
                           PropertyName="HeaderSelected" 
                           Value="Header1" />
                </i:EventTrigger >
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: can u give a sample of what you want to achieve?

Comment: show us what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using an MVVM approach, and you have a viewmodel backing your view:

You're almost there with your use of triggers. You want to make use of the `Checked` event of the RadioControl, and combine it with a `InvokeCommandAction`:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateHeaderCommand}" CommandParameter="MyParam"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

In this example the ICommand `UpdateHeaderCommand` defined in your viewmodel is called whenever the radio control is checked. I've also passed a parameter to the command, `MyParam`, which the `UpdateHeaderCommand` could use to identify which radio button is checked.

If you're not using MVVM/viewmodels, then an alternative approach might be to create a `RadioButton_Checked` event handler in your code behind to handle the `Checked` event, and have **all** your radio buttons attach to that handler:

```
<RadioButton Name="RadioButton1" GroupName="Group1" Checked="RadioButton_Checked"/>
<RadioButton Name="RadioButton2" GroupName="Group1" Checked="RadioButton_Checked"/>
```

and

```
private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Update your header ...
}
```

You would have to inspect the `sender` to figure out which radio button was checked.